# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type is define. While two beans of same type

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

This is first time I am using @autowiring, I have a example.

I want to use **Autowiring by TYPE** , SO that at Run time container injects appropriate Object and calls appropriate bean/method.

**1.INTERFACE**

```
  public interface Calculator {

    public int add(int a,int b);
}
```

**2.First Class**

```
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

public int add(int a, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int result=a+b;

    return result;
}
```

}

**3.Second Class**

```
public class CalculatorImpl2 implements Calculator{

public int add(int a, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int result=a-b;

    return result;
}
```

}

**4.REST CLASS**

```
@Component
@Path("/calc")
    public class CalculationService {
    @Autowired
    Calculator calculator;

    @GET
    @Path("/add/{a}/{b}/")
@Qualifier("calculatorImpl")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response serveAdd(@PathParam("a") int a,
            @PathParam("b") int b)
    {

        int result= calculator.add(a, b);

        return Response.status(200).entity(String.valueOf(result)).build();

    }


    @GET
    @Path("/sub/{a}/{b}")
@Qualifier("calculatorImpl2")
    public Response serveSub(@PathParam("a") int a,
            @PathParam("b") int b)
    {
        int result= calculator.add(a, b);

        return Response.status(200).entity(String.valueOf(result)).build();


    }
}
```

**5.APPLICATION-CONTEXT.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.veke.rest" />

 <bean id="calculatorImpl" 
                  class="com.veke.calcImpl.CalculatorImpl"  autowire="byType"/>


  <bean id="calculatorImpl2" 
                  class="com.veke.calcImpl.CalculatorImpl2"  autowire="byType"/>

                  </beans>
```

**ERROR:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'calculationService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.veke.calc.Calculator
>   com.veke.rest.CalculationService.calculator; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [com.veke.calc.Calculator] is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2: [calculatorImpl, calculatorImpl2]**

Have I done correct things? Or I am wrong.

I have done this with my understanding of @autowiring.

Many Thanks :)

Edit:
`@Qualifier` is solution for this problem.(As i Have two beans with same type in context).
Its used to solve ambiguity problem.
`@Autowired` is **by Type**.

Comment: in which class ? @Quanlifier(what should i pass here)

Comment: Use it in `Rest` class and give you beans name in `aaplication-context.xml` and use those names in `qualifier` as `@Qualifier("calculatorImpl2")`.

Comment: It say NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type... check my edit whats wrong Now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have just one `Calculator` instance variable and make it behave as both `CalculatorImpl` and `CalculatorImpl2`. You need to make the following changes:

In `CalculationService`:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Impl1")
Calculator calculator;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Impl2")
Calculator calculator2;
```

Then you can use these instance variables in the respective methods.

Comment: Compile time error: The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Autowired

Comment: above changes made it work. But i have a question , Why cant I use same Calculator instance variable. As per my knowledge container injects appropriate object. That is what we say IOC.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Spring injects the dependencies when it constructs the object for you. Hence it can inject reference to only one object. In your case you needed same reference pointing to two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:
Change following files:

**APPLICATION-CONTEXT.xml :**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.veke.rest" />

 <bean name="Impl1" id="calculatorImpl" 
                  class="com.veke.calcImpl.CalculatorImpl"  autowire="byType"/>


  <bean name="Impl2" id="calculatorImpl2" 
                  class="com.veke.calcImpl.CalculatorImpl2"  autowire="byType"/>

                  </beans>
```

**Rest Class :**

```
@Component
@Path("/calc")
    public class CalculationService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Impl1"); //<-- qualifier used here.
    Calculator calculator;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Impl2"); //<-- qualifier used here.
    Calculator calculator2;


    @GET
    @Path("/add/{a}/{b}/")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response serveAdd(@PathParam("a") int a,
            @PathParam("b") int b)
    {

        int result= calculator.add(a, b);

        return Response.status(200).entity(String.valueOf(result)).build();

    }


    @GET
    @Path("/sub/{a}/{b}")
    public Response serveSub(@PathParam("a") int a,
            @PathParam("b") int b)
    {
        int result= calculator2.add(a, b);

        return Response.status(200).entity(String.valueOf(result)).build();


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for previous incomplete commment,But this change only adds the reslut on both different URI

Comment: got it working :) but I had to create two instances as commented by @mithun, Can I make it work with single instance?